# netcdf error -114 Bad type id

Tags: fortran, netcdf

Hi while I am executing following netcdf function getting an error..

```
    stat = nf90_create_par('/home/sachin/e_output.nc', IOR( NF90_NETCDF4,NF90_MPIIO ), MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_INFO_NULL, ncid_user)
    write(*,*)"creating netcdf file stat=",stat
```

error "bad type id", since return status value is -114

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: Yes, Why I am getting that error?

Comment: What makes you convinced it means  "bad type id"? Which reference did you use to assign -114 to   "bad type id"?  There is no type id in your line. Are you sure it comes from this command? It is always better to show a full compilable example.

Comment: nf90_create_par function returns the integer value of function execution. If it is executed successfully it returns 0 or It returns the error code to the variable (in this case variable 'stat').

Comment: I know that. But how do you know that it means "bad type id? It would be much better to see the whole code which you used.

Comment: Please use nf90_strerror(stat) to print out what the error code really means. nf90_strerror(-114) returns "NetCDF: Parallel operation on file opened for non-parallel access" for me. The error code for "bad type id" is -117.